# Keeping Drawing.Rectangles as reference in a 2d array isn't working as expected in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, reference, graphic

So I have my code drawing rectangles and circles inside a flowLayoutPanel. 
Afterwards I've made it so that when you click inside of the flowLayoutPanel, the rectangle you selected is shown on your left on a 2nd flowLayoutPanel as shown in the following picture:

[image: When the rectangle at position [0,0] is clicked]

But the problem is that whenever any other position is clicked, ie [0,1] or [2,3], the selected one isn't shown. I also know that the array works properly because when I change the code `flowLayoutPanel2.CreateGraphics();` to `flowLayoutPanel1.CreateGraphics();` inside of the mouse click event it works, but it changes the rectangles in the main container.

The following are the two methods that mess around with it. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
    private void DrawIt()
    {
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = flowLayoutPanel1.CreateGraphics();
        graphics.Clear(Form1.ActiveForm.BackColor);

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            {
                System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(50 * j, 50*i, 50, 50);
                rectangleGrid[i, j] = rectangle;
                graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
                graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Red, rectangle);
            }
        }
    }

    private void flowLayoutPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = e.Y / 50;
        int columnIndex = e.X / 50;

        System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = flowLayoutPanel2.CreateGraphics();
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rectangle = rectangleGrid[rowIndex, columnIndex];

        graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.BlueViolet, rectangle);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pens.Chartreuse, rectangle);
    }
```

Comment: How big is your `flowLayoutPanel2`? It looks small on the picture. Maybe it's just drawing the rectangle outside of the visible area?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Let me check that out real quick.
Edit: Yea that was it. Man what a simple solution. Thanks for the help. If you want, you should post an answer and I'll mark as best.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `CreateGraphics()`, use `e.Graphics` in the `Paint` event of the flowLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: @darthmaim can you explain why I should use that way? Is it because when it minimized all the graphics gets deleted (That's what's happening right now)

Comment: You could draw the map to a Bitmap and set that as the Image() property of a PictureBox.  Why use a FlowLayoutPanel here?